# Signal Sigabart issue when switching from Viewcontroller to another view controller..using this code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

i've created an app which loads another viewcontroller from main view controller.example from viewcontroller 1 to viewcontroller2...in viewcontroller1 if button is pressed it needs to load viewcontroller2.and in viewcontroller2 i got icarousel view too..Here is my code

```
 -(IBAction)showcoll:(id)sender{

CollectionsViewController *sec=[[CollectionsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
sec.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

NSLog(@"hi");
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
CGRect splashFrame =splash.frame;
splashFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.size.width;    

[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     splash.frame = splashFrame;

                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
[self.view addSubview: splash];

 }
```

and the issue which i got is

```
 2012-06-30 11:16:29.301 Minora[948:12203] Done!
 2012-06-30 11:16:31.195 Minora[948:12203] hi
 2012-06-30 11:16:31.198 Minora[948:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception      'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x6e82b70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource.'
 *** Call stack at first throw:
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x013e45a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02b97313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x013e44e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x00b3b677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
4   Foundation                          0x00b3b5e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
5   UIKit                               0x003eeff6 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 173
6   UIKit                               0x005b730c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0135a8cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
8   UIKit                               0x005b5d23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
9   UIKit                               0x005b7ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
10  UIKit                               0x0046d628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
11  UIKit                               0x0046b134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
12  UIKit                               0x0046b00e -[UIViewController view] + 56
13  UIKit                               0x0046ca3d -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 63
14  UIKit                               0x00468988 -[UIViewController _visibleView] + 90
15  UIKit                               0x0070a93c -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 354
16  UIKit                               0x003e281e -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 954
17  UIKit                               0x0066a619 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1381
18  UIKit                               0x0046f65d -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:withTransition:] + 3478
19  Minora                              0x0000317a -[ViewController showcoll:] + 218
20  UIKit                               0x003bb4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
21  UIKit                               0x0044b799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
22  UIKit                               0x0044dc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
23  UIKit                               0x0044c7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
24  UIKit                               0x003dfded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
25  UIKit                               0x003c0c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
26  UIKit                               0x003c5f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
27  GraphicsServices                    0x01539992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
28  CoreFoundation                      0x013c5944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
29  CoreFoundation                      0x01325cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
30  CoreFoundation                      0x01322f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
31  CoreFoundation                      0x01322840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
32  CoreFoundation                      0x01322761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
33  GraphicsServices                    0x015381c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
34  GraphicsServices                    0x01538289 GSEventRun + 115
35  UIKit                               0x003c9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
36  Minora                              0x00002ada main + 170
37  Minora                              0x00002a25 start + 53
 )
 terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you show some code of CollectionsViewController also?

Comment: I think you are presenting the other view the wrong way.

Comment: tks for ur answer..i solved it on my own...I found out the problem because of icarousel view i used...i assigned same icarousel to 2 UIView..That makes issue...

Answer (score 1):

This Sigabart is not happening when you present the modalViewController, but instead it looks like you are setting a `UIView` to a `dataSource` in your `CollectionsViewController` I'm guessing you're doing something wrong in the viewDidLoad, because you never actually see the view yet.

Comment: tks for ur answer..i solved it on my own...I found out the problem because of icarousel view i used...i assigned same icarousel to 2 UIView..That makes issue...

Comment: doesn't that mean my answer was right?

Answer (score 1):

Two questions:

1. You have not specified a nib name when you created `CollectionsViewController`. Did you mean to use `nil` for the nib name?
2. If you're not using a nib, I'm not sure where your `splash` view is being created, but I'm curious about your animation of the frame, and then animating the changing of that frame, but adding `splash` as a subview *after* you initiate the animation. Was it already on the view (and if so, why adding it again)? If it wasn't, (a) where are you creating it, and (b) why aren't you adding as a subview before the animation?

Comment: tks for ur answer..i solved it on my own...I found out the problem because of icarousel view i used...i assigned same icarousel to 2 UIView..That makes issue...